# Binning a discrete variable (preferably in dplyr)

Tags: r, dplyr

I would like to "bin" a large discrete variable by combining two consecutive rows into one bin. I would also like to call the bin by the first row value.

As an example:

```
x<-data.frame(x=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12),
              y=c(1,1,3,3,5,5,7,7,9,9,11,11))
x
```

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by "combining two consecutive rows"? Are you looking to perform some function on those two rows? Or just the act of grouping them within something like the `group_by` function in `dplyr`? 
Could you also explain what you mean by "call the bin by the first row value"? An example would be helpful.

Comment: I would like to create a new variable that will allow me to group_by in dplyr, but the current category of x is too detailed. Therefore I would like to aggregate by combining two rows. The new variable would have the value of the first row as values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Performing the steps as you exactly outlined them would be this:

```
library(dplyr)

x %>%
  mutate(bins = rep(1:(length(x) / 2), each = 2)) %>%
  group_by(bins) %>%
  filter(row_number() == 1) %>%
  ungroup()
```

However this would give you the exact same result (without the `bins` column) in one line of code:

```
x[seq(1, nrow(x), by = 2), ]
```

Answer (score 1):

We may use `gl` to create the grouping bin

```
library(dplyr)
x %>%
   mutate(grp = as.integer(gl(n(), 2, n())))
    x  y grp
1   1  1   1
2   2  1   1
3   3  3   2
4   4  3   2
5   5  5   3
6   6  5   3
7   7  7   4
8   8  7   4
9   9  9   5
10 10  9   5
11 11 11   6
12 12 11   6
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way using `seq` and `ceiling`.

```
x$bin <- ceiling(seq(nrow(x))/2)
x

#    x  y bin
#1   1  1   1
#2   2  1   1
#3   3  3   2
#4   4  3   2
#5   5  5   3
#6   6  5   3
#7   7  7   4
#8   8  7   4
#9   9  9   5
#10 10  9   5
#11 11 11   6
#12 12 11   6
```